# How to parse an html file to follow up a specific data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, fiddler

My target web site is: http://www.imkb.gov.tr/Home.aspx

Please focus this on that page: "XU100 64.882,72   -1.36 %" it is on top..

The exact target is **64.882,72** this value!...

What is the best way for this  value?

My platform: asp.net , c#

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847677/how-to-seek-a-string-variable-an-html-files-source-code/3847730#3847730

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you look at the source of the page, you will see that line looks like this:

```
<span id="ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_lblUlusal100">XU100 64.882,72&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
```

Should not be hard to look for the constant `ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_lblUlusal100` and what comes after.

Looking a bit more at the page it is clear it is being updated by AJAX (a Telerik control).  If you download fiddler 2 and take a look I'd bet be it would not be hard to figure out their API and get it straight from the source.  Reading it from a page seems a little round about to me.

---

**update**

Here you go:
Every 5 mins or so, page sends something like this:

POST http://www.imkb.gov.tr/Home.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.imkb.gov.tr
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://www.imkb.gov.tr/Home.aspx
Content-Length: 14762
Origin: http://www.imkb.gov.tr
X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.63 Safari/534.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=1gpydu4544juaf55h0xc3dus
ctl00%24ScriptManager1=ctl00%24ScriptManager1%7Cctl00%24Timer1&ctl00_cphMenu_ctl00_RadTabstrip1_ClientState=%7B%22selectedIndexes%22%3A%5B%220%22%5D%2C%22logEntries%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22scrollState%22%3A%7B%7D%7D&ctl00_cphChart_iseindexchart1_RadTabStrip1_ClientState=%7B%22selectedIndexes%22%3A%5B%220%22%2C%220%3A0%22%2C%221%3A0%22%2C%222%3A0%22%5D%2C%22logEntries%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22scrollState%22%3A

snip

dGExJEdlbmVyaWNDb250ZW50MTUPFCsAAQUPR2VuZXJpY19Db250ZW50ZAUhY3RsMDAkY3BoU2FnQm9sdW0kR2VuZXJpY0NvbnRlbnQ0DxQrAAFkZAUvY3RsMDAkY3BoSGFsa2FBcnpWaWRlb0Jhbm5lciR0bV9HZW5lcmljQ29udGVudDEPFCsAAWRkBR5jdGwwMCRjcGhPcnRhMyRHZW5lcmljQ29udGVudDIPFCsAAWRkBSJjdGwwMCRjcGhQYXphcmxhciRHZW5lcmljQ29udGVudDEwDxQrAAEFD0dlbmVyaWNfQ29udGVudGQFKWN0bDAwJGNwaEd1bmx1a0J1bHRlbmxlciRHZW5lcmljQ29udGVudDEzDxQrAAEFD0dlbmVyaWNfQ29udGVudGST8UDQlpGnx0YBRFx4m7Y34D0U5A

And gets back something like this:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Date: Sun, 03 Oct 2010 01:00:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 22017

62|updatePanel|ctl00_RadAjaxManager1SU||80|updatePanel|ctl00_ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_lblUlusal100Panel|XU100 64.882,72  |80|updatePanel|ctl00_ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_lblUlusal030Panel|XU030 82.390,23  |82|updatePanel|ctl00_ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_lblUlusalMaliPanel|XUMAL 100.123,14  |82|updatePanel|ctl00_ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_lblUlusalSinaiPanel|XUSIN 48.861,20  |140|updatePanel|ctl00_ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_imageUlusal100Panel||140|updatePanel|ctl00_ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_imageUlusal030Panel||141|updatePanel|ctl00_ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_imageUlusalMaliPanel||142|updatePanel|ctl00_ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_imageUlusalSinaiPanel||87|updatePanel|ctl00_ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_lblUlusal100DegisimPanel| -1.36 %|87|updatePanel|ctl00_ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_lblUlusal030DegisimPanel| -1.55 %|88|updatePanel|ctl00_ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_lblUlusalMaliDegisimPanel| -2.01 %|89|updatePanel|ctl00_ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_lblUlusalSinaiDegisimPanel| -0.13 %|0|hiddenField|_*EVENTTARGET||0|hiddenField|*_EVENTARGUMENT||14044|hiddenField|__VIEWSTATE|/wEPDwUENTM4MQ9kFgJmD2QWAgIDEGRkFg4CAw8WBB4HRW5hYmxlZGceCEludGVydmFsAqD+CmQCBw8PFgIeF0VuYWJsZUFqYXhTa2luUmVuZGVyaW5naGRkAgkPZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWAmYPZBYCZg8QZGQWAWYWBGYPZBYCZg9kFgJmDw8WBh4EVGV4dAUIVMO8cmvDp2UeC05hdmlnYXRlVXJsBWVqYXZhc2NyaXB0Omxhbmd1YWdlQmFyc1snY3RsMDBfY3BoTGFuZ19jdGwwMF9mbGFnTGlzdF9jdG

snip

iPanel,ctl00$ctl00$cphTicker$ctl00$imageUlusal100Panel,ctl00$ctl00$cphTicker$ctl00$imageUlusal030Panel,ctl00$ctl00$cphTicker$ctl00$imageUlusalMaliPanel,ctl00$ctl00$cphTicker$ctl00$imageUlusalSinaiPanel,ctl00$ctl00$cphTicker$ctl00$lblUlusal100DegisimPanel,ctl00$ctl00$cphTicker$ctl00$lblUlusal030DegisimPanel,ctl00$ctl00$cphTicker$ctl00$lblUlusalMaliDegisimPanel,ctl00$ctl00$cphTicker$ctl00$lblUlusalSinaiDegisimPanel|2|asyncPostBackTimeout||90|9|formAction||Home.aspx|4|pageTitle||İMKB|98|scriptBlock|ScriptPath|/ScriptResource.axd?d=lcMagBepDm3uqEhp4ZZIkOfRuU_Z1n_24IMfgjw79puiRGCI0X9_3XYgvubs5myx0&t=4efa241b|98|scriptBlock|ScriptPath|/ScriptResource.axd?d=lcMagBepDm3uqEhp4ZZIkOfRuU_Z1n_23WPnJeX5XRrOvxpExhC2_vq3NYmi9puU0&t=4efa241b|581|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|if(typeof ($telerik)!='undefined'&&!$telerik.isSafari){var links=document.body.getElementsByTagName('link');if(links&&links.length>0){var documentHead=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];if(documentHead){for(var i=links.length-1;i>=0;i--){var linkTag=links[i];if(linkTag.className=='Telerik_stylesheet'){var thLinks=documentHead.getElementsByTagName('link');if(thLinks&&thLinks.length>0){var j=thLinks.length-1;while(j>=0&&thLinks[j--].href!=linkTag.href){};if(j>=0){continue;};};if($telerik.isIE){linkTag=linkTag.cloneNode(true);};documentHead.appendChild(linkTag);};};};};};|3218|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Telerik.Web.UI.RadAjaxManager, {"_updatePanels":"","ajaxSettings":[{InitControlID : "ctl00_cphChart_iseindexchart1_RadTabStrip1",UpdatedControls : [{ControlID:"ctl00_cphChart_iseindexchart1_RadTabStrip1",PanelID:""},{ControlID:"ctl00_cphChart_iseindexchart1_RadMultiPage1",PanelID:""}]},{InitControlID : "ctl00_cphChart_iseindexchart1_RadMultiPage1",UpdatedControls : [{ControlID:"ctl00_cphChart_iseindexchart1_RadMultiPage1",PanelID:""}]},{InitControlID : "ctl00_Timer1",UpdatedControls : [{ControlID:"ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_lblUlusal100",PanelID:""}]},{InitControlID : "ctl00_Timer1",UpdatedControls : [{ControlID:"ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_lblUlusal030",PanelID:""}]},{InitControlID : "ctl00_Timer1",UpdatedControls : [{ControlID:"ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_lblUlusalMali",PanelID:""}]},{InitControlID : "ctl00_Timer1",UpdatedControls : [{ControlID:"ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_lblUlusalSinai",PanelID:""}]},{InitControlID : "ctl00_Timer1",UpdatedControls : [{ControlID:"ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_imageUlusal100",PanelID:""}]},{InitControlID : "ctl00_Timer1",UpdatedControls : [{ControlID:"ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_imageUlusal030",PanelID:""}]},{InitControlID : "ctl00_Timer1",UpdatedControls : [{ControlID:"ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_imageUlusalMali",PanelID:""}]},{InitControlID : "ctl00_Timer1",UpdatedControls : [{ControlID:"ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_imageUlusalSinai",PanelID:""}]},{InitControlID : "ctl00_Timer1",UpdatedControls : [{ControlID:"ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_lblUlusal100Degisim",PanelID:""}]},{InitControlID : "ctl00_Timer1",UpdatedControls : [{ControlID:"ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_lblUlusal030Degisim",PanelID:""}]},{InitControlID : "ctl00_Timer1",UpdatedControls : [{ControlID:"ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_lblUlusalMaliDegisim",PanelID:""}]},{InitControlID : "ctl00_Timer1",UpdatedControls : [{ControlID:"ctl00_cphTicker_ctl00_lblUlusalSinaiDegisim",PanelID:""}]},{InitControlID : "ctl00_cphChart_iseindexchart1_RadTabStrip1",UpdatedControls : [{ControlID:"ctl00_cphChart_iseindexchart1_RadTabStrip1",PanelID:""}]},{InitControlID : "ctl00_cphChart_iseindexchart1_RadTabStrip1",UpdatedControls : [{ControlID:"ctl00_cphChart_iseindexchart1_RadMultiPage1",PanelID:"ctl00_RadAjaxLoadingPanel1"}]},{InitControlID : "ctl00_cphChart_iseindexchart1_RadMultiPage1",UpdatedControls : [{ControlID:"ctl00_cphChart_iseindexchart1_RadMultiPage1",PanelID:"ctl00_RadAjaxLoadingPanel1"}]}],"clientEvents":{OnRequestStart:"",OnResponseEnd:""},"defaultLoadingPanelID":"","enableAJAX":true,"enableHistory":true,"links":["App_Themes/imkbTheme/default.css","App_Themes/imkbTheme/Panelbar/styles.css","App_Themes/imkbTheme/TabStrip/styles1.css","App_Themes/imkbTheme/Telerik/Grid.Telerik.css","/WebResource.axd?d=amYphA-0bPJeUJ3f2MWC9cDMaVsfb5JruqQDL2BA-uj2wLoxdJspOYFmAQ64SpW0GsRili9aNLED-pMP967YKVx4BQvkVw41cVPpujevY6Wl4hwZKl5xHg2&t=633758219960000000","/Sitefinity/ControlTemplates/Search/searchCommonLayout.css","/WebResource.axd?d=amYphA-0bPK6q7TUfp4lRhfNYzJQ2FPpMyJO7CL6Be2RQT-3IpQ3emdqJw56-kOz38BtycR_5N65G73e9FwsqqCxydyqPEEOYiTmyBjqfpY5nfRdAEU44A2&t=633758219960000000"],"styles":[],"uniqueID":"ctl00$RadAjaxManager1","updatePanelsRenderMode":0}, null, null, $get("ctl00_RadAjaxManager1"));
});
|

Comment: @trying feedler..It will be great If I can reach the api...I am not good at feedler either but I will try to get this impossible data..

Comment: I know sir, I mean getting the exact api seems hard to me since there are a lot of js and other files are listed in fiddler...

Comment: @blgnklc : Well no one said reverse engineering was easy.  You will probably need to make use of some skills here.  Since we don't know exactly when or how often the data is loaded.  One thing you can do is have fiddler record the whole page load -- save that to a file -- then search for `64.882,72` in the responses.  When you find the response that returns the value, you then know the call that asked for it.  Bingo Jackpot.  (or whatever it is called in Turkish).

Comment: @ I have seen the details. It is amazing sir.. I am looking for an app example to sniff that data...